# In wso2 esb how to read endpoint from a file

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

In wso2 esb what is the best practice for Endpoint maintenance. From some article I got to know that we can read from file So, if this the best approach how achieve this one.

Answer (score 3):

In a scenario where the endpoint is saved as a file within the carbon registry (You can even upload the file via management console or can use [WSO2 EI Tooling](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/Working+with+Endpoints+via+Tooling) to create an endpoint template), we can read the content of the endpoint as follows.

1. Add the endpoint registry resource.
   [image]
2. Log the endpoint content using the following synapse configuration. (Can even retrieve specific attributes within the endpoint using their xpath expressions)

```html
 <log level="custom">
    <property name="Endpoint Content:" expression="$ctx:endpointFile//*"/>
    <property name="Endpoint URL:" expression="$ctx:endpointFile//*[local-name() = 'address'][1]/@uri"/>
 </log>
```

You can see the logged endpoint content as below.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 ways to Endpoint Maintenance.

1. Using ESB Tooling
2. From Command Line
3. Using a Script

More details can be found in [WSO2 Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Working+with+Endpoints).

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer, this does not explain how it is to be done.